# They asked me where I live. Is that question correct?

Tags: reported-speech

I know in reported speech we have to change the present simple to the past simple but this question really makes me wonder if I can write it like
They asked me where I live.
Since it's something always true.

Comment: They asked you (in the past) where you lived (at the time they asked).

Comment: Backshift is not obligatory here. Assuming you haven't moved since the time of the original utterance, you can keep the original present tense if you wish.

Comment: ***No!*** In reported speech we ***don't have to*** change the present simple to the past simple. We ***can***, and we often ***do***, but it's not obligatory. Both ***live*** and (backshifted) ***lived*** are fine for your context. Unless the speaker is talking about something that happened a long time ago (when he lived somewhere else), in which case only ***lived*** would make sense.

Comment: *They asked me where I live* is not a question, it's a statement.

Comment: @JasonBassford That's true, but the subordinate clause "where I live" is an interrogative (embedded question), which is obviously what the OP meant. Sometimes we have to cut learners a little slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change to the past tense.

It is correct to leave the tense unchanged. It is more common to leave the tense as present tense when answer hasn't changed since the time when the question was asked.

> Yesterday he asked me where I live.
>
> Ten years ago he asked me where I lived.
>
> You already asked me what I am eating five minutes ago.
>
> You asked me what I was eating when I first met you last week.

Comment: Some people do insist on *sequence of tenses*. “Last week I met someone who knew Kathy” (and probably still knows Kathy). “The professor explained how hemoglobin worked” (and still works).

Comment: @AntonSherwood: Anyone who *insists* on backshifting in all such contexts has limited understanding of how English works. It's a common stylistic choice, not a "rule"..